# How can I get WPF and Windows Phone templates in Expression Blend 2013?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a few installs of Visual Studio Express 2013 (Windows Phone, Windows Store and Desktop) but the only options there are when creating a new project in Blend are for Windows Store apps.

Opening a WPF solution in Blend that was created in Visual Studio 2013 just shows the XAML and no design view loads or is available.

I have browsed the Blend install directory and there are Silverlight and WPF templates in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp` (although no Windows Store templates).

I have tried repairing the Visual Studio Express Desktop but with no luck.

This webpage implies there is a [Blend for Visual Studio 2013 SDK for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195709.aspx) but I cannot find the download link for this. There was some mention as well in another Stackoverflow post that the templates would be available in update 2 for Visual Studio but I have installed this and there are no extra templates.

Any idea how I can access the templates so I can edit in Blend?

Comment: What was the order of installation for each?

Answer (score 2):

I found this on this [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/)

```
You can download Blend for Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Express 
for Windows, Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, and Visual Studio 
Professional 2013 and higher.
```

Here, I took a snapshot;

[image: Expression Blend]

```
So, when you download Visual Studio Express for Windows or Windows Phone, you get Blend
for Visual Studio 2013 but for Windows (WinRT / Store) & Windows Phone. You don't get 
Blend for WPF or Sliverlight Applications. If you do want Blend for Visual Studio 2013
Full Edition, that you can get by downloading Visual Studio 2013 Professional or Higher.
You can try Visual Studio 2013 Professional or Higher free for 90 Days.
```

Here is the Link;
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2

Hope this helps you understand, why you are not able to see the designer in Blend 2013 when you open a WPF project created in Visual Studio 2013.